# how to define multiple (WITH AS FUNCTIONS) in a single query?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, with-statement

trying to  define multiple functions under a single with clause. which we normally do for CTE's. But for functions the same is not working. Please suggest solutions please.

```
With function dt ( b as number) 
return number is 
n number ; 
begin 
select  1 into n; 
return n ; 
end ; 
dt2 ( c as number) 
return number is 
n1 number ; 
begin 
select  1 into n; 
return n1; 
end ; 

select dt(1) , dt2(1) from dual
```

when using only dt i am able to get o/p but not with dt2.

Comment: Is `SELECT 1 INTO n` legal in 12c? I'd have thought you'd at least have to use `SELECT 1 INTO n FROM DUAL`. ??? Also, your second function doesn't define the variable `n` although you're SELECT-ing into it. ???

Comment: sorry that was a typo. i did use from dual. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working with the following example:

```
with 
  function x(p_NUM in number) return number
  is
    n number;
  begin
    SELECT 1 INTO N FROM DUAL;
    --
    return N;
    --
  end ; 
  --      
  function Y(p_NUM in number) return number
  is 
    N1 NUMBER;
  begin
    SELECT 2 INTO N1 FROM DUAL;
    --
    return N1;
    --
  end ; 
--
select X(1), Y(1)
from dual;
```

Cheers!!